# Do this series converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let,
$$\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nn^2}{n^2+1} \space (1)$$

This is an alternate series, so I applied the Leibnitz test. Let $a_{n}=\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$ be a sequence, if $a_{n}$ is decreasing and $\lim a_{n}=0$, then the given series $(1)$ converge.

But, $\lim \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=1$, so the Leibnitz test fail.

If I study the absolute value series, one have:

$$\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nn^2}{n^2+1}=\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \begin{vmatrix}\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{n^2+1}\end{vmatrix}=\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \begin{vmatrix}(-1)^n\end{vmatrix}\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$$

By the necessary convergence test if $\lim a_{n}\neq0$, then $\sum a_{n}$ diverges. The $\lim a_{n}$ was already found, and is equal to $1$, so the absolute value series diverges and one can't conclued anything about the given $(1)$ series.

Is there any test for alternate series that I can apply in order to say if the series $(1)$ converge or diverge? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already shown that it diverges.  $n$-th term test tells you that if the limit of $a_n$ is not equal to zero, as you have shown, then the series diverges.

Comment: I shown that $\sum |a_{n}|$ diverge. I learn that if $\sum |a_{n}|$ diverge, I can't say anything about $\sum a_{n}$.

Comment: The argument you used to show that that series diverged was using the $n$-th term test though.  Adding the factor $(-1)^n$ makes the sequence diverge even more.

Comment: Now I understand. If the convergence tests that I applied were inconclusive, then by applying the necessary convergence test directly I could conclued that the limit is not zero. There is no limit! So the series diverges. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As $n\to \infty$, the terms you are summing converges to $\pm 1$.
How could sum possibly converge?

In other terms your series converges as much as: $$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty (-1)^n$$